# How to make some of my rectangles Golden (Ratio)?

Tags: java, swing

i'm not too sure on how to make it so when a rectangle is drawn onto the screen, there's a chance that it will be golden. Here's the current code i have for my game to randomly produce random rectangles:

```
public void drawRectangle() {
    rects.clear();

    int x = (int) (Math.random() * getWidth());
    int y = (int) (Math.random() * getHeight());
    int width = (int) (Math.random() * (getWidth() / 4));
    int height = (int) (Math.random() * (getHeight() / 4));

    if (x + width > getWidth()) {
        x = getWidth() - width;
    }

    if (y + height > getHeight()) {
        y = getHeight() - height;
    }

    Color color = new Color(
            (int) (Math.random() * 255),
            (int) (Math.random() * 255),
            (int) (Math.random() * 255));

    rects.add(new Rect(x, y, width, height, color));

    repaint();
}
```

And heres the code i tried using to make it golden, although this was taken from online, i was jsut trying to get it working: EDIT: This code below is effectively now useless, but i'll keep it in the psot in case its of use

```
public static double golden(int n) {
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    return 1.0 + 1.0 / golden(n-1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    System.out.println(golden(n));
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks a bunch yet again

Comment: What makes a rectangle golden?

Comment: the width and height needs to be golden, so it follows the golden ratio. Im personally not too sure what this is, other than that the golden ratio is 1.61803398875

Comment: So, I assume that if you put `height` into the `golden` method, it will give you the `width`

Comment: I stillneed the code that i currently have in drawRectangle as i still need it to draw random normal rectangles. Should i make a new method solely for making golden rectangles too, or add the code into current method the rest is in. EDIT: The above code i had for golden ratio is completely wrong it turns out and doesn't work

Comment: @MadProgrammer really quick, i added this code                        
 `JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1));
               buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Menu"));
               buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Restart"));
               buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Pause"));`                                     to try make a side menu pane (on the left) with buttons on it, however it doesnt show up on my programme?

Comment: The question is, do you want to randomly generate the width and height and then determine if it's a golden rectangle, or do you want to randomly create a golden rectangle

Comment: i want it to randomly create a golden rectangle every so often, and then the users answer whether it is golden or not, hence the need for my code being able to generate normal non golden rectangles, and golden rectangles every so often

Comment: You can use [`Random#nextBoolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBoolean--) to determine if you should create a golden rectangle, from there you can use it again to determine if you want to calculate the width or height

Comment: @MadProgrammer sorry if i'm annoying you but  don't understand aha? So, my current code only generates random rectangles on click, but i can use Random#nextBoolean and make some of them Golden?

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is, you want to, randomly, create a golden rectangle (and possibly, randomly create the width or height)

You could use `Math.random` and if it's within a specified range (ie 0.75-1.0), generate a golden rectangle, but I'm lazy, so I'd use `Random#nextBoolean` to make the decision itself, for example...

```
private Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

public void drawRectangle() {
    rects.clear();

    double x = (Math.random() * getWidth());
    double y = (Math.random() * getHeight());
    double width = 0;
    double height = 0;
    if (random.nextBoolean()) {
        if (random.nextBoolean()) {
            width = (Math.random() * (getWidth() / 4));
            height = width * 1.618;
        } else {
            height = (Math.random() * (getHeight() / 4));
            width = height * 1.618;
        }
    } else {
        width = (Math.random() * (getWidth() / 4));
        height = (Math.random() * (getHeight() / 4));
    }

    if (x + width > getWidth()) {
        x = getWidth() - width;
    }

    if (y + height > getHeight()) {
        y = getHeight() - height;
    }

    Color color = new Color(
            (int) (Math.random() * 255),
            (int) (Math.random() * 255),
            (int) (Math.random() * 255));

    rects.add(new Rect(x, y, width, height, color));

    repaint();
}
```

Because the calculation of the golden width/height will generate a `double` value, I've opted to use `double`s, you'll find that `Rectangle2D.Double` will be useful here and `Graphics2D` can paint `Shape` objects (see `Graphics2D#draw` and `Graphics2D#fill`)

Comment: i'm getting a cannot find symbol- class Random when i use this code within mine, the code is within my Class called "Game" and not within a separate class (For generating the rectangles). Should i just make a new class solely for this, or find a way to add it to my already existing class?

Comment: Have look at the [JavaDocs for `Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBoolean--) to see what package it belongs to?

Comment: Okay i managed to get that working (Sorry for being stupid) but now  i jsut get an error along this line     `rects.add(new Rect(x, y, width, height, color));`    saying incompatible types, lossy conversion from double to int

Comment: ignore what this message said its still broken :(

Comment: As I said in my question, I'm using `double`s, because the golden ratio calculation generates `double`s, you'll need to update your code to support them in your `Rect` class, but I also suggest that you can use `Rectangle2D.Double` to support them and the `Graphics2D` API is capable of painting these `Shape`s

Comment: i've gone through my rect class, imported the two things you mentioned, and amde appropriate changes within the Rect class (Changed from int's to doubles). However, now im getting the exact same error message, but within the ret class this time. The line `super(x, y, width, height);` is saying it? This line of code is within the public Rect part of the Rect class

Comment: What did your `Rect` class extend from?

Comment: it extends Rectangle

Comment: Use `Rectangle2D.Double` instead

Comment: Yep, any class you use outside of the current package needs to be imported ;)